# Using mutate(across to create multiple new columns for different cutoff values for one existing column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate

I'm trying to create new columns (binary variables) for different cutoff values of one existing column. Here's what I tried:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10))

cutoffs <- c(-1, 0, 1)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = everything(),
    .names = "{.col}_cutoff_{cutoffs}",
    .fns = setNames(lapply(cutoffs, function(cut) as.integer(x <= cut)), paste0("cutoff_", cutoffs))
  ))
```

This keeps returning an error. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Your function does not return a function. Note that `.fns` should be a function. In your case it is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return a function. Note that .fns should be a function. In your case it is not a function

You can write the functions outside the mutate. Note that there is no need of setting name since you are already using the `.names` argument

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(
     .cols = everything(),
     .names = "{.col}_cutoff_{cutoffs}",
     .fns = lapply(cutoffs, \(cut) \(x)as.integer(x <= cut))))

            x x_cutoff_-1 x_cutoff_0 x_cutoff_1
1  -0.5644413           0          1          1
2  -0.7638014           0          1          1
3  -0.6759922           0          1          1
4   0.1781104           0          0          1
5   0.6114332           0          0          1
6   2.3147138           0          0          0
7  -1.3219765           1          1          1
8  -0.7737188           0          1          1
9   0.1433984           0          0          1
10  1.6090404           0          0          0
```